# Can a user be charged each time for an app upgrade

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I haven't post my app to the app market yet, so i am just wondering if a user buys our app, would it be possible to charge him for every upgrade or every upgrade has to be free.

I ask this question because our company has to make the decision whether we keep adding more features to the app or we make different apps to do different things and charge our clients accordingly.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: I know of several medical apps that update their dictionary's with a server.  It could be possible to monetize that.

Comment: No i think what my boss want is continuously adding more features as different upgrades to the one app in the app store and charge users for that. If they don't upgrade, they can still use the app, and they will not be able to use the functions in the upgrade. So the upgrade definitely would be new code. Those upgrades will have nothing to do with each other so logically they are different apps. And we would like to let user upgrade through app store.Thanks a lot for your reply. I guess we will just implement different apps and publish them separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot (currently) charge for updates.

You might consider unlocking additional functionality using in-app purchase.

Comment: Thanks. that's all i wanna know.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by 'update.'. In the case of maybe a database, dictionary-type, or even a game (possibly, though unlikely), app updating some kind of database (SQLite, XML, etc.) is allowed, but downloading code is a no-no as stated in the developer guidelines.  If you must charge, the downloading of a database is the only possible way, otherwise in-apps will fill the gap.

Comment: Thanks. All my boss wanna know is after we release an app to app store, can we continuously add more features to it as upgrades (through app store) and charge the user for each upgrade. Each upgrade would do different things so the one app would be like a set of different apps. But if that's not the case, then i guess we can implement different apps and publish them separately.